# Getting MYSQL UTC_TIMESTAMP via Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

Is it possible to get the UTC_TIMESTAMP from MySQL via EF5?

I've tried

```
var z = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP(), UTC_TIMESTAMP() + 0;");
```

Which simply returns -1... not so useful.

Edit: Solved!

```
var utcTime = db.Database.SqlQuery<DateTime>("SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP();");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really using EF, but this did the trick:

var utcTime = db.Database.SqlQuery("SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP();");